# How to update time component alone to 23:59 of an existing date time field in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called end date which contains date and time. How do i update the time component alone to 23:59 using oracle sql? eg. 05/08/2018 03:12:45 to 05/08/2018 23:59:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to just extract the date part and add the time part as string and then convert it back to date type.

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET end_date = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') || ' 23:59:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 WHERE ...
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one easy way.

```
select to_date(
extract(day from to_date('05/08/2018 03:12:45' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) || '-' ||
extract(month from to_date('05/08/2018 03:12:45' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) || '-' ||
extract(year from to_date('05/08/2018 03:12:45' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) || '-'||
' 23:59:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Extract the day, month, year and then concatenate with 23:59:59

A short way to do the same will be -

```
select trunc(to_date('05/08/2018 03:12:45' , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) + 1 - 1/24/60 from dual;
```

1. Use trunc to truncate the time and make it 00:00:00
2. Add 1 day to it
3. Subtract 1 minute from it. 1/24/60 is. 1 day / 24 hours / 60 minutes

Comment: Why you add 1 and subtract 1/1440 instead of add 1439/1440?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov tbh, out of habit :( I am used to generally adding +1 or -1 for my day to day calculations, But also I think its easier to understand rather than 1439/1440, but yes its purely out of habit

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view simplest way is

```
UPDATE <your_table>
SET end_date = trunc(end_date)+1439/1440
```

Explanation. trunc(date) truncate time part from date. 1439/1440 means 23 hours 59 minutes.